# Zoho mail says 535 Authentication Failed in Node Js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, zoho

I am creating an Application using Node Express and MongoDB. After user creation a successful mail want to send to the user. I am using zohomail and can able to use those username and password to login zohomail online. But when I try to send mail I got an error as

```
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535 Authentication Failed',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
```

**This is my code**

[helped snippet from](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/264/how-to-send-an-email-gmail-outlook-and-zoho-using-nodemailer-in-node-js)

```
if (user) {
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
      user: 'sample@sample.com',  //zoho username
      pass: 'password'  //zoho password## Heading ##
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'sample@sample.com',
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: 'Created Successfully',
    html: '<h1>Hi ' + req.body.fname + ',</h1><p>You have successfully created.</p>'
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(setting.status("User created Successfully, Please Check your Mail"))
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you [Nguyen Manh Tung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6603052/nguyen-manh-tung)

As said in comment.

I had enabled 2 Factor Authentication (2FA) in Zoho mail.

So, I login my account [here](https://accounts.zoho.com/u/h#home) and go to the Two Factor Authentication and get Application specific password.

After that I used the application specific password instead of zoho mail password in Node Js.

```
if (user) {
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
      user: 'sample@sample.com',  //zoho username
      pass: 'application specific password'  //Not zoho mail password because of 2FA enabled
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'sample@sample.com',
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: 'Created Successfully',
    html: '<h1>Hi ' + req.body.fname + ',</h1><p>You have successfully created.</p>'
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(setting.status("User created Successfully, Please Check your Mail"))
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are from India, replace `smtp.zoho.com` with `smtp.zoho.in` keeping other things same. Sample is given below:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.zoho.in",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.ZOHO_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.ZOHO_PASSWORD,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i just changed zoho.com to zoho.eu and it worked properly.

Answer (score 2):

1/ Check your password.

2/ Check 2 factor authentication

Did you enable 2 factor authentication with Zoho?

If you enabled it, you need to create application specific password.

Comment: Yeah my password is ok. And 2FA enables with Google Authenticator. How can I create application specific password?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing authentication errors after adding 2 Factor authentication and generating an App password. If you created your Zoho Mail account from the EU please change your host to the following:

`host: "smtp.zoho.eu"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're from India, use `smtppro.zoho.in`, it would look something like this

```
const transporter: Transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "smtppro.zoho.in",
  host: "smtppro.zoho.in",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ZOHO_MAIL_ID,
    pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ZOHO_MAIL_PASSWORD,
  },
});
```