# send email from godaddy hosted email in nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send an email from GoDaddy email in nodemailer but it is not sending.

```
exports.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
         host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",  
         secureConnection: true,
         port: 587,
         auth: {
             user: 'my@domain',
             pass: '*********'
         }
  })
```

this is my error

```
 Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication Failed for my@domain
at SMTPConnection._formatError
```

code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535 Authentication Failed for my@domain',
responseCode: 535,
command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodemailer Invalid login: 535 Authentication Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983495/nodemailer-invalid-login-535-authentication-failed)

Answer (score 1):

TLS (Transport Layer Security) need to be enabled and `secureConnection: false,` Try This configuration, it's should works! ;-)

```
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({    
    host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",  
    secure: true,
    secureConnection: false,
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    },
    requireTLS:true,
    port: 465,
    debug: true,
    auth: {
        user: "my@domain",
        pass: "**********" 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you but Still  it is not working and showing the same error

Comment: @Prithiraj Goswami
Hmmm. If the console shows the same error again ... then check your Login and password again. Are you sure they are correct? You can also try changing the SSL Port: 465 to 587

Comment: Yes I logged in with the same email password it logged in successfully

Comment: With port 587 this error is coming.

[Error: 139698950920064:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  function: 'ssl3_get_record',
  reason: 'wrong version number',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  command: 'CONN'
}

Comment: I have one more idea. Remember that in the options for sending the message, FROM must be the same as USER in auth!!!!. And if that doesn't help, check out this link. Good luck and Don't give up easily ;-) Best regards    https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/920

Comment: Yes, I have the same user in FROM. Thanks

Comment: You're Welcome!  If I were you, I would be looking for GoDaddy in the settings panel right now, that seems to be the best clue.

Comment: The solution is working for me !!