# Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed when using Mailgun

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer, mailgun

How to fix below error when trying to send mail using nodemailer?

I was trying to find solution on internet. but all answers not working for my situation.

Similar question : [nodemailer Invalid login: 535 Authentication Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983495/nodemailer-invalid-login-535-authentication-failed)

Coz I am using **mailgun** platform.

```
sendRawEmail Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed
at SMTPConnection._formatError (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:790:19)
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1542:34)
at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:546:26)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:953:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:755:14)
at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:193:44)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535 Authentication failed',
responseCode: 535,
command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
```

I checked all info SMTP, SMTP_USER, SMTP_PASS, SMTP_PORT several times.
They are all correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution with reset password.

Maybe it is mailgun bug.
After generate new password, it started to work well.
I hope this help others who use mailgun.